# How can I remap a key that triggers multiple events?

Tags: keyboard, remapping

I recently bought a small folding keyboard that has a .com key (which I never use) but doesn't have a del(ete) key which I use a lot.  Using xev I  see that pressing .com triggers a bunch of events:

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x1c3, subw 0x0, time 6648508, (126,-8), root:(1360,270),
    state 0x0, keycode 60 (keysym 0x2e, period), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2e) "."
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2e) "."
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x1c3, subw 0x0, time 6648510, (126,-8), root:(1360,270),
    state 0x0, keycode 60 (keysym 0x2e, period), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2e) "."
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x1c3, subw 0x0, time 6648510, (126,-8), root:(1360,270),
    state 0x0, keycode 54 (keysym 0x63, c), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (63) "c"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (63) "c"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x1c3, subw 0x0, time 6648522, (126,-8), root:(1360,270),
    state 0x0, keycode 54 (keysym 0x63, c), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (63) "c"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x1c3, subw 0x0, time 6648522, (126,-8), root:(1360,270),
    state 0x0, keycode 32 (keysym 0x6f, o), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (6f) "o"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (6f) "o"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x1c3, subw 0x0, time 6648546, (126,-8), root:(1360,270),
    state 0x0, keycode 32 (keysym 0x6f, o), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (6f) "o"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x1c3, subw 0x0, time 6648546, (126,-8), root:(1360,270),
    state 0x0, keycode 58 (keysym 0x6d, m), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (6d) "m"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (6d) "m"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x1c3, subw 0x0, time 6648547, (126,-8), root:(1360,270),
    state 0x0, keycode 58 (keysym 0x6d, m), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (6d) "m"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Of course I can't remap keycode 60 (or any of the others here) to del because I need . and c.  What can I do here?